# Текст в переменной JS

Tags: javascript, php, текст

Есть текстовый файл с некоторым содержанием, я пихаю его в div с помощью js  (innerHTML). Вот пример:

```
var inside = '<?php include("main.txt");?>';
```

В общем, проблема такая: если в текстовом файле содержание расположено не в одну строку, то 
 s добавляет в начало текста апостроф и выдает такую ошибку "unterminated string literal". Как выйти из затруднительного положения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
 var inside = '<?= str_replace("\n", "\\\n", file_get_contents("main.txt")) ?>';
```

Добавлю что, по хорошему, этого тоже не достаточно т.к. если в текстовом файле будет одинарная кавычка, то это тоже приведет к ошибке.

Я бы вообще не использовал PHP, нужно содержимое текстового файла? Ajax в помощь, ИМХО такой подход ужасен

Comment: Так и сделал, Спасибо.
Сначала не получалось, оказалось что нужно не \n , а \r писать.
На всякий случай меняю и \n и \r на <br>